# How to twist object maintaining uniform section?

Tags: modeling

I have a long slender 'cylinder' with the following section that I'm trying to twist about the length (z-axis)

[image: Profile section]

I've tried both the Lattice and Simple Deform modifiers but the center becomes thin like it's being stretched out.

[image]

It's what you would expect if you twisted an existing object but I'm looking for something more like a column of an old building.  This picture is not exactly what I want but close enough to illustrate the goal.

[image]

I've only been using Blender for a few weeks so I apologize if this is super simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your topology lacks some horizontal edge loops, that's why it shrinks on its middle, so go in *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> then scroll (or <kbd>+</kbd>) to increase the amount of edge loops, then let's twist again!

Comment: That worked perfectly! So simple. Thank you.